# Java JComboBox array only shows one element

Tags: java, swing

I have a java program that will create an array of JComboBoxes depending on the user input. If the user input is one, then the comboBox is displayed. If the input is greater then one, I seem to get a plain JFrame.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class test
{
    public static void main (String Args [])
    {
    JFrame processDetail = new JFrame("Enter information for processes");
    JPanel panelDetail = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    String [] Processes = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"};
    processDetail.setSize(500,500);
    processDetail.setVisible(true);

        JComboBox [] AT = new JComboBox[4];  //initailse drop down, numProcc is user integer...
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            AT[i] = new JComboBox(Processes); //processes is array of numbers
            System.out.println(i); //a check to see it was looping
            panelDetail.add(AT[i]);
        }
        //add the panel to the frame
        processDetail.add(panelDetail);
        }
    }
```

Why don't I seem to get the required amount of comboboxes?

Comment: Putting `System.out.println(i);` in your code for troubleshooting was a good idea.  Why not share with us what output it generates?  It would make your problem a lot easier to diagnose.

Comment: Because it was looping fine. Lets say numProcc was 3.....it would display 0,1,2

Comment: It's working fine here. If i set numProcc to be 4, it shows 4 combobox's. The problem must be somewhere else in your code.

Comment: i put the code in for what I was using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you place `processDetail.setVisible(true);` after `processDetail.add(panelDetail);` it should work fine.

```
JFrame processDetail = new JFrame("Enter information for processes");
JPanel panelDetail = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
processDetail.setSize(500, 500);
//processDetail.setVisible(true); Not here,
String[] processes = {"1" , "2", "3", "4"};

JComboBox[] AT = new JComboBox[4];  //initailse drop down, numProcc is user integer...
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    AT[i] = new JComboBox(processes); //processes is array of numbers
    System.out.println(i); //a check to see it was looping
    panelDetail.add(AT[i]);
}
//add the panel to the frame
processDetail.add(panelDetail);
processDetail.setVisible(true); // <--- but here.
```

Because if you set it to visible and then add some components, they will not show because nothing tells it to set them visible.

Answer (score 1):

You have just discovered one of the pitfalls of failing of perform Swing operations in the AWT Event Dispatch Thread.

[Swing is single-threaded.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading)  Nearly all Swing methods *must* be executed only in the Event Dispatch Thread.

If they aren't, they may *seem* to work, but you will get unpredictable behavior, like what you are seeing now.

Your problem will go away if you move all of your code into a Runnable and pass that Runnable to [EventQueue.invokeLater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater-java.lang.Runnable-) (or [SwingUtilities.invokeLater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater-java.lang.Runnable-), which is a synonym for EventQueue.invokeLater).